# Testing a Promise within another Promise's .then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to understand how to resolve a Promise within another Promise.
The steps I'm looking to achieve are the following ones:

1. Get a `User` by its id through the `UserManager` (Functioning)
2. Alter its `firstName`
3. Save the `User` to the database through the `UserManager` (Functioning)

I'm looking to test the response of `UserManager.saveUser(user);` which returns `true` on success. But I'm getting an error.

---

`UserManagerTest.js`

```
//[...]

it("Should save a user to the database", function () {
    var response = UserManager.getUserByLogin("Foo.Bar@provider.com", "Test")
        .then(function (user) {
            user.firstName = "Macarena";
            return UserManager.saveUser(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("This error occured: "+error);
            return false;
        })
    return Promise.all([
        expect(response).to.eventually.be.true
    ]);
});

//[...]
```

---

Console output

```
  1) UserManager Save Should save a user to the database:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to be true
      at node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:305:22
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

---

`UserManager.js`

```
static saveUser(user){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, connection)=> {
            if(err) reject(err);

            connection.query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM User;", (error, results, fields) => {
                if(error) reject(error);

                var availableFields = {savable: [], primary: []};
                //[...]
                resolve(availableFields);
            });

            connection.release();
        });
    })
    .then((result) => {
        var usedFields = {savable: [], primary: []};
        //[...]
        return usedFields;
    })
    .then((result) => {
        var sqlParams = [];
        var sql = "UPDATE User SET";
        //[...]
        sql += ";";
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if(err) throw err;

            connection.query(sql, sqlParams, (error, results, fields) => {
                if(error) throw error;
                connection.release();
                return results.affectedRows == 1;
            });
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    })
};
```

Comment: Guessing here but, should your connection.release(); be inside the connection.query? It seems like you could be releasing the connection before you are getting the results back. I see nothing else that stands out to me.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) you're right but this doesn't alter the issue. Adding `console.log(results.affectedRows);` before the `return` statement shows the correct result. And testing this function correctly updates the values on the database.

Comment: Not the cause, but FWIW: `if(err) reject(err);` will continue to run the rest of the code (and will probably cause `connection.query()` to throw an error); once you've rejected the promise, do a `return` to prevent that (or use `if (err) return reject(err)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second `then((result)=> ...)` does not return anything, hence the `undefined`

The `return results.affectedRows == 1;` is inside a lambda. It returns on that lambda, not the surrounding `then``

You need to change the semantics of `pool.getConnection` to change it from a callback to a Promise. Wrap it in a Promise, resolve it and chain it, something looking like

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) {
             //see @robertklep comment
             try { connection.release(); } catch(e) { /* ignore ? */ }
             return reject(err);
        }

        connection.query(sql, sqlParams, (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error) throw error;
            connection.release();
            resolve(results.affectedRows == 1);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `reject(err);` requires a `return` statement while `resolve(boolean);` doesn't?

Comment: You should release the connection before throwing an error.

Comment: @faegy the `return` is only there to immediately exit the promise lambda; it does not actually return anything of interest. But before doing so you should release the connection as suggested by @robertklep

Answer (score 0):

MySql is async and does not return a promise.

```
function queryDB(result) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var sqlParams = [];
        var sql = "UPDATE User SET";
        //[...]
        sql += ";";
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
                return connection.release();
            }

            connection.query(sql, sqlParams, (error, results, fields) => {
                if(error) ? reject(error) : resolve(results.affectedRows == 1);
                connection.release();
            });
        });
  })
}
```

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719050/testing-a-promise-within-another-promises-then#comment72559523_42719050) about returning after rejection :) Also, release the connection _before_ returning, otherwise you end up with an empty pool.

Comment: True very true, I was tunnel visioned on the problem not the other issues. ;) However, reject/resolve do not return. This code obviously needs to be tested.